# How can I avoid using routerlink in bootstrap tabs in an Angular project?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, routerlink

I am trying to setup HTML bootstrap tabs, the most basic possible ones:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
  </div>
```

But because of routerlink in angular, I get redirected to https://localhost:5001/#profile instead of the div I am trying to open. I don't want to turn off routerlink because it is the main form of navigation for my site. I just want this one navbar to not use it. I haven't been able to find any way around this... Hopeful for an html solution, but open to anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `routerLink` instead of `href`.

See Angular [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink).